# What is a number theory book I can read in bed?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I am looking for a good book that is very easy going but not a "pop science" account i.e. something that goes through theory that would be on a basic undergraduate course for someone who finds the subject interesting but doesn't really care about total rigor. I missed a lot of the basics was I began my undergraduate in physics and to this day I have a hard time remembering what a number field is, but I find a lot of the stuff "cool". Like there are no rational points on a circle of radius 3? that's great, I only learned this yesterday! I want to learn more things like this, I can totally use this at parties!

Comment: William LeVeque has a fairly nice treatment of the subject ([Elementary Theory of Numbers](https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Theory-Numbers-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486663485/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1465516796&sr=8-1&keywords=William+LeVeque) has very little in the way of prerequisites, and [Fundamentals of Number Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Number-Theory-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486689069/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1465516904&sr=8-2&keywords=William+LeVeque) is slightly more advanced).

Comment: I always liked _One Fish Two Fish Red Fish Blue Fish_ by Seuss.

Comment: There's [Ash & Gross, Fearless Symmetry](https://www.amazon.com/Fearless-Symmetry-Exposing-Patterns-Numbers/dp/0691138710?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0)

Answer (score 2):

André Weil's *Number theory for beginners* is short and wonderful.

For a longer text, try [A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frint.html) by Joseph H. Silverman.

But I wouldn't read an interesting number theory in bed: I'd be itching to get up and try some examples and write some code to test conjectures and bring theorems out to life.